# Software Developer - change core skills to match current employer, or change employer to match core skills?

Tags: software-industry, career-development

Should an OOP developer only seek companies in tune with their desired direction and abilities?

Comment: What do they expect you to use instead? Why? And why is your boss telling you how to do your job?

Comment: @toddmo So it sounds a bit like you're doing maintenance on a system which is already designed as non-OOP, and you'd prefer to redo parts of it as OOP. But your boss wants you to just keep it how it is and do your maintenance task. Maybe it would be better redesigned, but if that's not your job... Personally I'd like to redesign it using a functional paradigm instead.

Comment: @toddmo You may have a valid point, but redesigning is redesigning and maintenance is maintenance. Consider if you're asked to repair a house that is built using old techniques and you tell the owner, "well I'd just tear it down and start over because it will be better". The owner has the right to decide if that's the course she'll take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do OOP work, you probably need to change jobs. There could well come a time that your employer is not so thrilled with you using company time to stay fresh on OOP when it doesn't serve the company agenda.

Look at a switch to OOP from your employer perspective for a minute.  Are you the only developer? Then you might be able to get a change in programming model accomplished.  If there's a number of other developers, the organization has momentum that is difficult to turn. Those other developers would also need to change models and may not have the skills so now it's also a big training and re-staffing issue.

Answer (score 3):

If your boss is not aware what object orientated programming is then that should be a massive red flag for the software shop.

If you are afraid that your skillset will atrophy unless you do at least 8 hours a day of practice then that should be a massive red flag for you as a developer, I have not written any code in Visual Studio for windows in over 10 years, but if I have to I am sure that I can hop back into it and hit 90% productivity in a matter of hours.

Unless the core product of said company is software components (so their main customer base is programmers) then there is no reason or indication as to why there is a need for a dramatic change, due to the fact that 100% of customers dont actually

(in my experience complete re-writes of projects tend to repeat all the same mistakes as the original software. )

Comment: @toddmo - superficially aware of the dominant programming paradigm of the last 20 years? You've got to be kidding.

Comment: @toddmo in 97 OOP already had a massive foothold in the industry, VB5, C++, Java, Ada, were all OO technologies that were rather prominent then (just to name a few) .. Some of your comments make it appear that you are extremely green to this field. There is a old saying, if it ain't broke dont fix it. The customers really dont care what tech something is built on (and nor should they. ) They care about having a product that works, and your boss cares about making sure that the customers have a product that works, I fail to see a real issue here